# Where am I making a mistake in my calculation ( deriving the dual form from the inequality )

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-programming, duality-theorems

I'm trying to do the derivation for the second problem on the page 13(slide 12) of this pdf : http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/ee236a/lectures/duality.pdf

I'm using Fenchel-Rockafellar duality. If we let $A$ from $X$ to $Y$, ( $(X,W)$ and $(Y,Z)$ are pairs hence $((X,Y),(W,Z))$ is a dual pair) and
$$f(x)=c^{T}x+\delta_{R_{+}^{n}}(x)$$
$$g(y)=\delta_{R_{+}^{n}}(y)$$
then $f^\star(w)=\delta_{R_{+}^{n}}(c-w)$ and $g^\star(z)=b^{T}z$ then the duality will be $\sup-\{\delta_{R_{+}^{n}}(c+A^\star z)+b^{T}z\}$ according to the Fenchel-Rockafellar duality. But how I read this is maximimize $-b^{T}z$ subject to  $c+A^\star z\geq 0$ which is not similar to the given duality. What am I doing wrong?

I'm using this pdf as a source https://people.math.ethz.ch/~patrickc/CA2013.pdf . You can find the definition I'm using from this pdf or Ican write them if needed.

Comment: Does the dual problem given on slide 2 not directly apply to the example on slide 13?

Comment: I just started to study this stuff i don't know how it exactly works. When i use the same method on the dual problem given on slide 2 i get the same exact thing when i take the conjugates and stuff. But for the problem on slide 13 if what you said is the approach then why do i need to apply the same stuff twice? @littleO

Comment: On slide 13 one of the primal variables is $t$, but I don't see $t$ in the work you've shown. Where's $t$?

Comment: oops i when i said page 13 i meant page 13 of the pdf, it corresponds to slide 12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $y = -z$. Then the dual problem you derived can be written as maximizing $b^T y$ subject to $A^T y  \leq c$. This agrees with the dual problem shown on slide 12.

By the way, the Cheridito lecture notes you linked to look quite good, but Vandenberghe's lecture notes are self-contained. In this case you can derive the dual problem by first converting the primal problem to inequality form and then applying the result on slide 2.

You might also consider reading chapter 5 of the Boyd and Vandenberghe Convex Optimization textbook (which is free online). It gives a simple explanation of Lagrange duality, which is an easy way to derive the dual problem shown on slide 2. (Not that there is anything wrong with the Fenchel duality approach; it's also very useful.)